# List all paths from directed graph whose vertices belongs to single cluster

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I need all sub-graphs/path from single directed graph whose vertices belongs to specific cluster as explained in below code.

```
g = nx.DiGraph()

# cluster to vertices mapping, so [a, b, c] vertices 
# belongs to cluster 1 and so on..
cluster = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    2: ['d', 'e'],
    3: ['f', 'g'],
    4: ['h'],
    5: ['i'],
    6: ['j'],
}

g.add_edge('a', 'd')
g.add_edge('a', 'e')
g.add_edge('b', 'd')
g.add_edge('b', 'e')
g.add_edge('c', 'd')
g.add_edge('c', 'e')
g.add_edge('d', 'f')
g.add_edge('e', 'g')
g.add_edge('d', 'h')
g.add_edge('e', 'h')
g.add_edge('h', 'i')
g.add_edge('j', 'h')

pos = {}
pos['a'] = [0, 1]
pos['b'] = [0, 2]
pos['c'] = [0, 3]
pos['d'] = [2, 3]
pos['e'] = [2, 2]
pos['f'] = [3, 3]
pos['g'] = [3, 2]
pos['h'] = [2, -2]
pos['i'] = [0, -2]
pos['j'] = [4, -2]

nx.draw_networkx(g, pos)

## expected paths
# [a-e, e-g, e-h, h-i, j-h]
# [a-d, d-f, d-h, h-i, j-h]
# .
# .
# [c-e, e-g, e-h, h-i, j-h]
```

**My Input:**

[image]

**What I want as output:**

[image]
[image]

*There are 12 such paths/sub-graphs am interested in.*

I can think of modified DFS search with constrained of picking next node from cluster only but not sure about how to proceed. Please give me some pointer/algorithm/pseudo code for how to achieve desired output.

Comment: To clarify: do you want a) the subgraphs that correspond to your clusters (i.e. e.g. `nx.subgraph(g, cluster[1])`, or b) the subgraphs that consist of edges between clusters?

Comment: a) Didn't get that, gives me vertices back when I do `list(nx.subgraph(g, cluster[1])) = ['b', 'a', 'c']` b) Yes, edges between cluster node like [('a', 'd'), ('d', 'f'), ('d', 'h'), ('h', 'i'), ('j', 'h')]

Answer (score 0):

The function `nx.subgraph(G, nodes)` returns the subgraph of G induced on the given node set. According to your comment, you want the edges between the given cluster, so for cluster 1 and 2, we are talking about these edges:

[image]

There are many ways to get those edges. In my solution below, I compute them as the edges that remain when I induce the subgraph on the union of the two clusters and subtract the subgraphs induced on the individual clusters.

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()

# cluster to vertices mapping, so [a, b, c] vertices belongs to cluster 1 and so on..
cluster = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    2: ['d', 'e'],
    3: ['f', 'g'],
    4: ['h'],
    5: ['i'],
    6: ['j'],
}

g.add_edge('a', 'd')
g.add_edge('a', 'e')
g.add_edge('b', 'd')
g.add_edge('b', 'e')
g.add_edge('c', 'd')
g.add_edge('c', 'e')
g.add_edge('d', 'f')
g.add_edge('e', 'g')
g.add_edge('d', 'h')
g.add_edge('e', 'h')
g.add_edge('h', 'i')
g.add_edge('j', 'h')

pos = {}
pos['a'] = [0, 1]
pos['b'] = [0, 2]
pos['c'] = [0, 3]
pos['d'] = [2, 3]
pos['e'] = [2, 2]
pos['f'] = [3, 3]
pos['g'] = [3, 2]
pos['h'] = [2, -2]
pos['i'] = [0, -2]
pos['j'] = [4, -2]

nx.draw_networkx(g, pos)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# my answer using cluster 1 and 2 as examples

def get_subgraph_between_clusters(g, cluster_1, cluster_2):
    """Returns the subgraph induced on g that contains all edges between
    the clusters 1 and 2.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    g -- networkx graph object
        The graph

    cluster_1 / cluster_2 : iterable of nodes
        The node clusters. Clusters are assumed to be disjoint,
        i.e. any node in cluster 1 is assumed to be absent from cluster 2.

    Returns:
    h -- networkx graph object
        The induced subgraph
    """

    # get subgraph induced on individual clusters, and compute union of subgraphs
    g_1 = nx.subgraph(g, cluster_1)
    g_2 = nx.subgraph(g, cluster_2)
    g_1_g_2 = nx.union(g_1, g_2)

    # get subgraph induced on union of cluster node sets
    g_12 = nx.subgraph(g, set(cluster_1) | set(cluster_2))

    # compute difference
    h = nx.difference(g_12, g_1_g_2)

    return h


h = get_subgraph_between_clusters(g, cluster[1], cluster[2])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(h, pos, edge_color='red', )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I dont want _all edges between 2 cluster_ but sub-graph/path going thru all clusters single point. I updated my question regarding my output expectation, sorry for any confusion caused in original question.